# VBA hyperlinks names and addresses

Tags: vba, hyperlink

I'm trying to pull all hyperlinks in an excel spreadsheet into a new worksheet. I want column A to show the text from the hyperlink, and column B to show the hyperlink address.

I've written the code below, and all of column B works fine, however the values in column A are not all coming over, and they don't match the hyperlink addresses in column B. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
Sub extract_links()
    Dim hyp As Hyperlink
    Dim ReadCols As Long
    Dim ReadWriteRow As Long
    ReadWriteRow = 1
    ReadCols = 6

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a:b").Clear

For c = 1 To ReadCols
    For Each hyp In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Columns(c).Hyperlinks
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a" & ReadWriteRow).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ReadWriteRow, c).Value
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("b" & ReadWriteRow).Value = hyp.Address
        ReadWriteRow = ReadWriteRow + 1
    Next
Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time you need to change this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a" & ReadWriteRow).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(ReadWriteRow, c).Value
```

into this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("a" & ReadWriteRow).Value = hyp.Range.Value
```